# How to enable Network Policies in Docker for Mac with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-mac, kubernetes-networkpolicy, docker-desktop

Is there an easy way to enable `Network Policies` in `single-node k8s cluster` managed by **Docker Desktop for Mac**?

Comment: I opened an issue about this [Document whether or not NetworkPolicy works in Docker Desktop for Mac](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/9535).

Answer (score 5):

A `single-node k8s cluster` managed by `Docker Desktop for Mac` is imply a VM provisioned by the Docker for Mac Daemon that is then bootstrapped with a Kubernetes cluster. Docker has extended this solution in some ways to make it easier for developers to use but it is effectively similar to using [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/).

A [NetworkPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) is a Kubernetes resource and as you have discovered, it is not *enabled* in your environment by default. This is because the NetworkPolicy resource requires a [controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/) to be installed to enabled the enforcement of NetworkPolicy rules after they have been declared. Many applications can be installed to provide this functionality. The most common way is by installing a [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) like [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart).

After you do this, Calico will be able to enforce your NetworkPolicy rules that you have defined. They will automatically move from the `Pending` to `Ready` state in the cluster.